# how t to change width and color of table generated by table library?

Tags: codeigniter

How I can change the color and width of table generated by table library in CodeIgniter

Controller

```
    <?php
class Addbalance extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
                if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
                    $this->load->library('pagination');
                    $this->load->library('table');
                    $config['base_url']='http://localhost/elvan/addbalance';
                    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('products')->num_rows() - 1;
                    $config['per_page']=1;
                    $config['num_links']=10;
                    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
                    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
                    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
                    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                    $data['records']=$this->db->get('products',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(2));
        $this->load->model('Addbalance_m');

        $this->load->view('addbalance_v',
            array('order'=>$this->Addbalance_m->index(),
        'provider'=>$this->Addbalance_m->get_provider_data()
            ,'mydata'=>$data

        ));
    }
    else {

        redirect('login','refresh');
    }
    }
}
?>
```

View

```
<?php
            $this->table->set_heading('id','product name','quanity','yoo','yoo');
            echo $this->table->generate($mydata['records']);
            echo '<div id="pagination">'.$this->pagination->create_links().'</div>';
            ?>
```

I want to use for each if that possible, but I don't know how to fetch the columns from this library in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by modifying the Table class template. [Documentation Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html#changing-the-look-of-your-table)

To add a particular class to the `<table>` and another to all `<tr>`s for example.

```
$template = array(
    'table_open' => "<table class='my-table-class' id='my-fancy-table'>",
    'row_start' => "<tr class='my-row-class'>",
);
//apply the above to the table
$this->table->set_template($template);
```